# Reinstall behavior of cabal-dev

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal-install

The latest cabal-install that I've been using (0.13.3, from the darcs repo) is nice; it lets you know when you might break your GHC installation with reinstalls. What I want to know is this: suppose a `cabal install foo` *would* perform a reinstall that *would* break my GHC. What would happen if I `cabal-dev install foo` instead? Would I be able to avoid breaking GHC? Could I actually make use of the `foo` package in a cabal-dev sandbox, or would it just be a broken sandbox?

[Example: yesod](http://hpaste.org/57561), GHC 7.4.1, cabal-dev 0.9 built from github source, Cabal 1.14.0 library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to clarify, if I am understanding you right, you are not breaking GHC in either case. I believe you are referring to installing a package, which then reinstalls one of the underlying dependencies of another package, therefore breaking that other package's dependency chain and preventing it from properly working/compiling when used. Simply removing .ghc from your home folder and re-doing cabal installs typically resolves this problem, albeit in a really painful way.

When you use cabal-dev, all the cabal install steps and ghc-pkg register steps are done in a local sandbox environment. Your global/user ghc packages are **not at all touched**. Since you typically instantiate one cabal-dev sandbox per project, clashes like described above don't typically happen.

To get to your question - it depends entirely on what is already installed in that particular cabal-dev sandbox. If there are no conflicts, it wouldn't break anything. If you are forcing a `--reinstall`, you might have to `--reinstall` any packages in the local cabal-dev sandbox that depend on the package you just reinstalled.

In any case, your GHC installation itself would not break (or be altered in any way) and you can always `rm -rf cabal-dev` under your project folder and redo `cabal-dev install`.

Hope this helps.